# Flash ActiveX control throws floating point exceptions in x64

Tags: flash, com, activex, atl, floating-point-exceptions

I have an MFC dialogue which uses a flash player active x control. I have no problems in x86 program but when built for x64 I start getting floating point exceptions thrown in the message loop for the dialogue. I can handle the first of these but not all of them.

The creation of the control is done like so in OnInitDialog()

```
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *LPAtlAxWinInit)();
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *LPAtlAxGetControl)(HWND hwnd, IUnknown** unk);
#define MsgLoopWhile(a) while(a) { GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0); DispatchMessage(&msg); }


LPAtlAxWinInit AtlAxWinInit = (LPAtlAxWinInit)GetProcAddress(
         LoadLibrary(_T("atl")),"AtlAxWinInit");
LPAtlAxGetControl AtlAxGetControl = (LPAtlAxGetControl)GetProcAddress(
         LoadLibrary(_T("atl")),"AtlAxGetControl"); 
HRESULT hr = AtlAxWinInit();
if (FAILED(hr))
    return FALSE;
m_hFlashWnd = CreateWindow(_T("AtlAxWin"), m_strFileName, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, this->GetSafeHwnd(), 0, 0, 0);

if(!m_hFlashWnd)
{
    ::AfxMessageBox(LoadStr(IDS_FLASH_NOT_INSTALLED));
    ::PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
    return FALSE;
}

CComQIPtr<IUnknown, &IID_IUnknown> pComI = NULL;
hr = AtlAxGetControl(m_hFlashWnd, &pComI);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return FALSE;

MSG msg;
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> pComBrow = pComI;
CComPtr<IDispatch> pDisp;
if(pComBrow) 
    MsgLoopWhile( !pComBrow->get_Document(&pDisp) && !pDisp );         // Document loading loop
CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pComHtml = pDisp;
CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> pElems;
hr = pComHtml ? pComHtml->get_embeds(&pElems) : -1;
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    CComVariant id;
    pDisp = NULL;
    MsgLoopWhile( pElems && !pElems->item(id,id,&pDisp) && !pDisp );
}
```

The exceptions are thrown in the last loop.

Resetting the exception flags or using a SEH handler does not work

The cal stack is as follows

> mshtml.dll!CLayout::GetElementLayoutTransform()
>       mshtml.dll!CLayout::CalcSize()
>       mshtml.dll!CLayout::CalcTopLayoutSize()
>       mshtml.dll!CView::EnsureSize()
>       mshtml.dll!CView::EnsureView()
>       mshtml.dll!CDoc::RunningToInPlace()
>       mshtml.dll!CServer::Show()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::_ShowMsoView()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::ActivateMe()
>       mshtml.dll!CServer::ActivateView()
>       mshtml.dll!CServer::DoUIActivate()
>       mshtml.dll!CServer::DoVerb()
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::Navigate()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::_ActivateMsoView()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::UIActivate()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectView::UIActivate()
>       ieframe.dll!CBaseBrowser2::_UIActivateView()
>       ieframe.dll!CBaseBrowser2::v_ActivatePendingView()
>       ieframe.dll!CWebBrowserSB::v_ActivatePendingView()
>       ieframe.dll!CBaseBrowser2::_ExecShellDocView()
>       ieframe.dll!CBaseBrowser2::Exec()
>       ieframe.dll!CWebBrowserSB::Exec()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::_OnReadyState()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::_OnChangedReadyState()
>       ieframe.dll!CDocObjectHost::OnChanged()
>       mshtml.dll!CBase::FirePropertyNotify()
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::SetReadyState()
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::SetInteractiveInternal()
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::RequestReadystateInteractive()
>       mshtml.dll!CMarkup::BlockScriptExecutionHelper()
>       mshtml.dll!CHtmPost::Exec()
>       user32.dll!DefWindowProcWorker()

Comment: Do you happen to have a call stack at exception time?

Comment: Also note: it only started happening in Win7 SP1